# Using the same component for different Routes with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a `PageBuilder` component that dynamically builds edit/list pages according to a configuration file. I want to have dynamic routes (like "/collection/list", "/collection/edit/123123", "/dashboard", etc.) that use the same `PageBuilder` component.

I'm having trouble getting this to work - if I'm in "/collection/list" for example, when clicking on a link to "/collection/edit/1231" doesn't work. Only a refresh to that URL works (and vice-versa).

I tried putting my initialization code `PageBuilder`'s `componentWilLReceiveProps` but it seems to call it every second.

My routes look like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRedirect to="/dashboard" />
  <Route path="/:page/:collection/:action(/:entity_id)" component={PageBuilder}  />
  <Route path="/:page" component={PageBuilder} />
</Route>
```

And my PageBuilder:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.createSectionsHTML = this.createSectionsHTML.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSave = this.onSave.bind(this);
}

getPageName() {
    return this.props.params.page.replace(/-/g, '_').toLowerCase();
}

componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.action = this.props.params.action;
}

componentWillMount() {
    let pageName = this.getPageName();
    this.props.dispatch(setInitialItem(pageName));
}

componentDidMount() {

    let pageName = this.getPageName();
    let { collection, entity_id } = this.props.params;

    if (collection && entity_id) {
        let { dispatch } = this.props;
        dispatch(getCollectionEntity(collection, entity_id, pageName));
    }
}
```

Any ideas of how to re-render the page each time I redirect to a different route?

It would be great if I could unmount and re-mount the component when redirecting, but I'm not sure how to go about telling React Router to do that....

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make `this.state` such that it will control how your component gets rendered.

Now, within `componentWillReceiveProps`, check the `nextProps` argument

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
  if( <check in nextProps if my route has changed> ) {
    let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    // make necessary changes to the nextState Object by calling
    // functions which would change the rendering of the current page
    this.setState({ nextState });
  }
}
```

This would make `componentWillReceiveProps` take action only when the route changes.

Now in your render function,

```
render() {
  const { necessary, variables, to, render } = this.state;
  let renderVariables = this.utilityFunctionsReqToRender(someArgs);
  return (
    <toRenderJsx>
      ...
    </toRenderJsx>
  )
}
```

This would make your component "refresh" whenever the route changes.

Comment: Thanks! The way my PageBuilder works doesn't really rely on ``this.state`` but I may change it so that it does (I'm using Redux for my app-wide state). Another problem I've run into with this approach is that I know when my location changes, but if I were to refresh the page, I have no way of knowing that I "changed" route (since ``nextProps`` and ``this.props`` are apparently identical...) 
But I will try playing around with this solution, I think this is a good starting point. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I got this to work (well, there are some minor issues, but the routing works!) by changing render to rely more on ``this.state``. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated since React 16.3.0
> (as says a warning in the browser console)

Reference :
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

So **componentDidUpdate** can be used to get the new state and reload data depending on params

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate " +prevState.id);
    reloadData(prevState.id);
}
```